# Matlab lookup table

Tags: matlab

I've got a function that acts as a lookup table in which I compute the minimum of a matrix given a specific row for each column, and I do the opposite for another matrix. I do that to find the indices of the minimum element in these two matrices. Then I extract the element of another two matrices using those elements.

```
function [x1,x2] = lookup_tab(y1,y2,X1,X2,Y1,Y2)
row = (size(Y1,1)+1)/2;
col = (size(Y2,2)+1)/2;

[min1,m] = min(abs(Y1(row,:)-y1));
[min2,n] = min(abs(Y2(:,col)-y2));

x1 = X1(n,m);
x2 = X2(n,m);
```

X1, X2, Y1, Y2 are matrices while y1, y2, x1, x2 are scalars.

How can I do the same in case I don't want to check for rows or columns, but inside the main diagonal for the first matrx Y1 and for the opposite diagonal for Y2?

Comment: what do you want as ouput? For example if the matrix is `[2,4;3,1]`, do you want the ouput to be 2, because the 2nd element of the diagonal is the lowest or do you want 4 as ouput because that's the linear index of the the smallest diagonal element?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the diagonal elements of a matrix using the `diag` function.
Assuming that you want to extract the `n-th` element of a third matrix `X3` where `n` is the the index of the lowest element of the vector `dY3=diag(Y3)` you could use this:

```
[~,o]=min(abs(diag(Y3)-y3));
dX3=diag(X3);
x3=dX3(o);
```

In your case it would be something like

```
[~,o]=min(abs(diag(Y1)));
[~,p]=min(abs(diag(fliplr(Y2))));
```

Comment: I ment something like: can I do a some kind of a diagonal scan of the matrix? Basically exactly what my function is doing right now but rotated of 45°. Scan the main diagonal for the first matrix Y1 for example, and scan for the opposite diagonal for the other matrix.

Comment: @Shika93 Ok sorry I don't get what you want. `min(abs(diag(Y1)));` is checking the main diagonal of Y1 for the minimum value and `[~,p]=min(abs(diag(fliplr(Y2))));` is checking the opposite diagonal of Y2. Isn't that what you want?